# Error: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

Следующие 2 запроса возвращают целевые результаты

```
     select sysdate from dual;--19.08.2015

     select to_char(to_date('19.08.2015','DD.MM.YYYY'),'YYYY/MM/DD') from dual;
--2015/08/19
```

Вопрос : 
Можно задать месяц через буквы ? Если да, то на каком языке задавать и как посмотреть настройки ?

```
 select to_date('15-JAN-10')  from dual;
```

Возвращает ошибку:

> SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
>   01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и через буквенный код, но он более сильно привязан к установленным языковым стандартам

```
select to_date('15-ЯНВ-10', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
select to_date('15-JAN-10', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
```

За настройку языка отвечает параметр `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`. Просмотреть настройки можно через запрос

```
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
```

Так же можно жестко указать язык

```
select to_date('15-JAN-10', 'DD-MON-YY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN')  from dual;
```

Comment: Гениальные ответы которые приятно читать . Благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Да, месяц буквами задавать можно, только надо указать формат даты.
Например

```
select to_date('15-янв-10', 'dd-mon-yy') from dual;
select to_date('15-JAN-10', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
```

Как именно задается месяц можно посмотреть в настройках NLS 
или выполнить такой запрос:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yy') from dual
```

Подробнее о форматах даты можно почитать [тут](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)